# Create Axios instance with taking token from AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, async-await, axios, asyncstorage

In my React Native App, I want to create an Axios instance to send headers to the backend with a token taken from `AsyncStorage`. However, the following `Token()` always returns an object( Promise ) instead of actual token so that 'Authorization' header is something like `[Object object]`.

```
import axios from 'react-native-axios'
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage"

const Token = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then(
        token => token
      );
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  }

export default axios.create({
      baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.100:8080/api',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ Token(),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
})
```

How can I take the actual token and use it in axios instance?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Below is how I managed to solve the problem.

As @Prithwee said, I decided to use axios( not `react-native-axios`) interceptors and set it up in **App.js** as follows.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DrawerNavigator from './Utils/DrawerNavigator'
import {
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';
import axios from 'axios'
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage"

axios.defaults.baseURL='http://192.168.1.100:8080/api'

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer "+token
    }
    return config
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you get null value for await AsyncStorage.getItem('token') anytime? I am use the same code like you but while using application sometimes await AsyncStorage.getItem('token') returns null token.

Comment: Maybe you haven't set the token first using `AsyncStorage.setItem("token",value)`?

Answer (score 4):

A better way would probably be using [`axios interceptors`](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors). this way you can both intercept the request and send your tokens and also when you send refreshed tokens in response you can get that and save them in async storage.

Answer (score 1):

By using @Pavindu's solution, I've implemented this solution that could be implemented all throughout any components needed.

**base.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://yourAPIaddress.com'

const apiInstance = axios.create()

apiInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    async config => {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
        //console.log(token)
        if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
            //console.log(config.headers.Authorization)
        }
        return config
    },
    error => {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
)

export default apiInstance
```

**Your component**

```
import apiInstance from '../api/base'


export default () => {
    const [stores, setStores] = useState([])
    
    use Effect(() => {
        apiInstance
            .get('../api/stores')
            .then(res => {
                setStores(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                alert(err)
                console.log(err)
            })
    },    [])
    
    return [stores]
}
```