# AsyncStorage always returns {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

```
async function getTokenFromAsync() {
  const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@User_Token');
  return userToken;
}

export default {getTokenFromAsync};
```

Im trying to get userToken from asyncStorage but it return me this {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null},
Im using react native

Comment: What are you storing in key `@User_Token`.

Comment: sir im storing user jwt token in  asyncStorage but in the above function i want to get the token and return them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not resolving the Promise hence your "weird" output.

This is the way that I have my get Function defined:

```
  const getData = async (key) => {
    // get Data from Storage
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      if (data !== null) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

You can then get the Data by calling the Function with your Key.

```
  await getData("yourKey")
  .then(data => data)
  .then(value => {
    a state or constant = value
    console.log("yourKey Value:  " + value)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wait to resolve the promise where you are using it like

```
getTokenFromAsync().then((userToken)=>{
  console.log(userToken);
});
```

Comment: sir how do i store this token in a global variable. because i want to use this token inside axios instance. `const authAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://192.168.18.70:4000",
  headers: {

    token: userToken,
  },
})
export default authAxios;`

Comment: @ijazbacha you can use `axios interceptors` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033617/create-axios-instance-with-taking-token-from-asyncstorage